# How to export from ASP.NET to Powerpoint 2007?

Tags: asp.net, sql, export, powerpoint

I'm working on a project that I'm trying to export data from textboxes in asp.net website project to a powerpoint file. I writing ofcourse in C#.
The whole concept is to use the data the a user inserts to the text boxes and they are sent after clicking a OK button directly to a powerpoint file. I'm using OFFICE 2007 so I'm using powerpoint 2007 for this.
A similar concept that I'm already using in the website project is doing the same thing but exporting to a WORD format file. I bumped against this following site a software to perform this and it's called: SoftArtisans. There website is http://www.softartisans.com/ .
Now, if somebody has a clue or a tutorial how I can do this, Export to a powerpoint file I'll be very thankful.
  I am also using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 to save the data in the database, so if maybe someone knows how to export the data from the textboxes from the website TO the database and then TO the powerpoint file that could help to.

Thank you very much for your help and support.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Office XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205(office.12).aspx)

HTH